# Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.ToTitleCase”, or the name ... when editing cell value

Tags: sql-server

When I try to edit a field value in my table (using SSMS) I get the above error.
I get the same error when trying to run an update query like this:

```
update Users
set fieldvalue = 'aaa'
where ID = 123
```

I looked at the Column Properties to see if there is any Compute field specification but could find any.
How this function is linked to this field?
Where is it coming from?

Comment: Please define `change a cell value` - SQL Server has no "cells" or "fields", it has rows and columns. How are you editing the value? If I _had_ to guess I'd say "Edit top n rows" in SSMS, but you'll need to edit these details into your question.

Comment: Are you sure you are not editing a view instead of a table? Otherwise, perhaps there is a computed column elsewhere in this table which uses this missing function.

Comment: Did you check if there are any triggers on this table? Looks like some typo in some "hidden" code... such as "dbo. xyz" instead of "dbo.xyz".,..

Comment: I am editing a table and not a view. There are no computed columns for any of the columns on this table. There are no triggers on this DB at all.

Comment: Can you check the constraints for your columns? Maybe one uses (tries to) a custom function. Something like CHECK (dbo.ToTitleCase(someColumm) = some_other_value). Although, function names suggests an action, not a check.

Comment: Instead of digging around various parts of the user interface, consider scripting out the entire table and just scanning down the generated definition until you find the mention of this function!

Comment: Apparently you were right. there was a trigger on table. I disabled it and was solved. Thanks

Comment: @ItaiMo Please write that as an answer and accept it, so others don't waste time coming to answer  a question that is already resolved!

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurred because of trigger on the table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rssjj.jpg)